# Using findall regex expression method python

Tags: python, regex, list

I am using the regex python module to find all of the key phrases from a legal document. one of which is under  5 U.S.C. § 8452(a) but it only prints and finds the sentence and stops at the first period; so instead of my output reading:

> The Board has jurisdiction over this appeal under 5 U.S.C. § 8452(a)

, it reads

> The Board has jurisdiction over this appeal under 5 U.

instead. Here is my code

```
  ruling_corpora  = map(lambda x: x[0], re.findall('([^.]*?(I find|In sum|agree|affirm|disagree|I conclude|In light of| under| this appeal| The ALJ| I determine| we| based on| for the reasons| pursuant to| the decision is| jurisidiction|section|§+\d |conclude)[^.]*\.)', tokenized, re.I | re.DOTALL | re.M))

    reduce = 0
    for r in ruling_corpora:#*
      reduce -=5
      big_list=[]
      big_list.extend(ruling_corpora)
      rc_list=[]
      rc_list.append(set(r))
      big_string= "".join(str(x)for x in  big_list)
      if len(big_string.split('.'))<= 3:
        while len(big_string.split())<=200:
          print("Ruling Content: {} \n".format(big_string))
          break
        break
    else:                                  
      summary=summarize(big_string,word_count=250+reduce)
      print("Summarized Ruling: {}\n".format(summary))
      break
   break
```

Comment: Your regex is written in such a way that it stops matching at a dot. Clearly that's not where you want it to stop. So where _do_ you want it to stop?

Comment: I want it it to match until the end of a sentence. However within some sentences there are multiple dots such as The Board has jurisdiction over this appeal under 5 U.S.C. § 8452(a). I want to capture this whole sentence using the keyword 'under'. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is stopping at the first literal dot.

```
([^.]*?( _snipped lots of text_ )[^.]*\.
                                # ^^^^^^
```

The marked (^^^^) part captures all the text that is not a dot + the literal dot, then it is done.

That is `The Board has jurisdiction over this appeal under 5 U.`

You do not show the real text, you can change this special case to capture anything thats not a `)` and then the `)`:

```
'([^.]*?(I find|In sum|agree|affirm|disagree|I conclude|In light of| under| this appeal| The ALJ| I determine| we| based on| for the reasons| pursuant to| the decision is| jurisidiction|section|§+\d |conclude)[^)]*\))', tokenized, re.I | re.DOTALL | re.M))
```

Comment: So the parenthesis are used to include all text and characters? I tried to run this in my code and it seems to through my output off. And I then have to join those sentences together so that they can be summarized through the Gensim Summarize module where at least two sentences are needed as inputs.

Comment: I get the following error when I change my code to yours:

Comment: raise ValueError("input must have more than one sentence")
ValueError: input must have more than one sentence

Comment: @user9608799  Use something like regex101 to get an idea what the regex does. Use https://regex101.com/r/aTvKGf/1 and look at the explanation. It looks for Characters that are not dots, followen by anythin in the ( ...| ...| ... ) `| == or`  and followed by more characters that are not a dot followed by a dot. You need to change this regex so it suits your needs. Provide more Text and exact data on what you want to match  - edit your question with it, do not put it into the comments and we might be able to help.

Comment: You regex captures all that in a bi capture group and a smaller one (which probably should be a non-grouping (?: ,,,, | ...| .... ) so it does not create new groups when you are only interested in the long sentence.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will take a look. I appreciate your help